# Wordpress automatically add text in <pre> tag

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to add text in a pre tag with functions in WordPress?

So when I put a script/code in a pre tag I want to auto add -

```
--Brought to you by (Website name)--
```

before the code/script I paste in.

Would look like this[image]

This is the HTML where the code goes

```
<pre class="prettyprinted copy-the-code-target" style=""><span class="pun"></pre>
```

then below the pre tag are many span tags that color the text

Comment: Modifying post content is usually done via the `the_content` hook, https://behind-the-scenes.net/using-wps-the_content-function-and-filter-hook/

Answer (score 1):

You can css only.  Otherwise you would need php and change filter `the_content`.

```css
pre {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  position:relative;
}

pre:after {
  content: 'hello world brought to you';
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 0px;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 200;
}
```

```html
<pre class="prettyprinted copy-the-code-target" style="">&lt;span class="pun"&gt;</pre>
```

**PHP**

```php
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_added_page_content');
function my_added_page_content($str) {
    $str = str_replace('</pre>', '</pre>Brought to you by...', $str);
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much the PHP version works. Not sure why but the CSS version didn't work.

The PHP you gave me put the Brought to you after pre but I changed it a little and now it's perfect.